# PowerShell command to split from output

Tags: powershell

My file looks like as shown below. I need only list of carId from the list.

I am trying to run command as:

```
Get-Content Carlist.txt | select-string carId | $_.split(':')[2].split(' ')

Attachments      : {}
State            : available
accessory            : {}
carId         : 53se
carType       : bmw

Attachments      : {}
State            : available
accessory            : {}
carId         : 23nu
carType       : audi

Attachments      : {}
State            : available
accessory            : {}
carId         : 94it
carType       : merc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the second command is a list, while in the third you're trying to act on single elements of that list. To do that you need [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1).
So your code becomes (including some fixes):

```
Get-Content Carlist.txt | select-string carId | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' }
```

Comment: its throwing error .. I am not sure why we need a "replace" in command as I need to split substring something like that .. PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop> Get-Content car.txt | select-string carId

carId         : 53se
carId         : 23nu
carId         : 94it  I need  53se  23nu  94it  only

Comment: I am getting this error Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'split'.
At line:1 char:62
+ ... t-string carId | Foreach-Object { $_.split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' }
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: I forgot to add the ToString() fix in my first answer. I used replace because the output of split depends on the whitespaces in the file which is not ideal